# How do I stop the event loop in pygame, after the maximum number of targets have been reached?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to end the event loop, where the number of targets that have been clicked has reached the same as the variable NoOfTargets(In this example, 10).

I thought that since the event loop handles all pygame events, I decided to validate to see if count is the same as NoOfTargets. count is originally set to 0. When a new target is clicked, it would add +1 to count.

```
            import pygame
            import random
            import math
            pygame.init()

            display_width = 800
            display_height = 600
            NoOfTargets = 10
            Target_radius = 10
            Frames_Per_Second = 60

            black = (0,0,0)
            white = (255,255,255)
            red = (255,0,0)

            def Target(Targetx, Targety , Targetr, colour):
                pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, colour, [Targetx, Targety], Targetr)
                pygame.display.update()

            def Pythagoras_Calculator(Target_x, Target_y, Mouse_X, Mouse_Y, Radius):
                Side = pow((Target_x-Mouse_X), 2) + pow((Target_y-Mouse_Y), 2)
                Distance = math.sqrt(Side)
                if Distance > Radius:
                    return False
                else:
                    return True

            def Get_Event_Time(GameTime):
                ListOfClickTime = []
                ListOfClickTime.append(GameTime)
                for x in range(len(ListOfClickTime)):
                    print(ListOfClickTime[x])

            ##    ListOfTime = []
            ##    TimeAtEventClick = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            ##    print("Time at event click", TimeAtEventClick)
            ##    print("Game Time:", GameTime)
            ##    TimeBetweenEvent = TimeAtEventClick-GameTime
            ##    print("Time between event", TimeBetweenEvent)
            ##    ListOfTime.append(int(TimeBetweenNewEvent))

            def Test(GameTime):
                print("Time Between EVENTS:",GameTime)

            gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
            pygame.display.set_caption("XD machine")
            clock = pygame.time.Clock()
            x = (display_width * 0.45)
            y = (display_height * 0.8)


            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            pygame.display.update()

            Random_x = random.randrange(0, display_width-Target_radius)
            Random_y = random.randrange(0, display_height-Target_radius)

            GameEnded = False
            while not GameEnded:
                count = 0
                Target(Random_x, Random_y, Target_radius, red)

                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        pygame.quit
                        quit()

                    elif count == NoOfTargets:
                        GameEnded = False
                        pygame.quit()

                    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        Mouse_X, Mouse_Y = event.pos
                        #GameTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()#Gets the time in milliseconds.
                        #Test(GameTime)
                        OnTarget = Pythagoras_Calculator(Random_x, Random_y, Mouse_X, Mouse_Y, Target_radius)
                        print(Mouse_X, Mouse_Y, OnTarget)
                        print(Random_x, Random_y)
                        if OnTarget == True:
                            count =+ 1
                            Random_x = random.randrange(0, display_width)
                            Random_y = random.randrange(0, display_height)
                            gameDisplay.fill(white)
                            pygame.display.update()
                            Target(Random_x, Random_y, Target_radius, red)
                            GameTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                            Get_Event_Time(GameTime)



            """if __name__ == "__Main__":
                pygame.init()
                Main()
                pygame.quit()
                quit()"""
```

I want it so that when count, which records how many targets that have been clicked, to be the same as NoOfTargets, so that eventloop will break and the game stops. Pls help me im new to pygame.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loop `count` is continuously set 0. `count = 0` has to be done before the main loop rather than inside the loop:

```py
count = 0
while not GameEnded:
    Target(Random_x, Random_y, Target_radius, red)
```

`count =+ 1` doesn't do what you expect it to do. =+ 1 will assign 1 to `count`. Note `=` is the assignment and `+` is just an positive sign for the value. The incremental assignment is `+=` rather than `=+`:

```py
if OnTarget == True:
    count += 1
```

The evaluation, whether `count` has exceeded the limit, is better be done outside the event loop. Note the event loop is executed if an event occurs only.
If the game should end, then `GameEnded` has sto be set `True` rather than `False`.

```py
if count == NoOfTargets:
    GameEnded = True
```

Further, don't do any drawing in the event loop:

```py
GameEnded = False
count = 0
while not GameEnded:
    Target(Random_x, Random_y, Target_radius, red)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit
            quit() 

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            Mouse_X, Mouse_Y = event.pos
            OnTarget = Pythagoras_Calculator(Random_x, Random_y, Mouse_X, Mouse_Y, Target_radius)
            print(Mouse_X, Mouse_Y, OnTarget)
            print(Random_x, Random_y)
            if OnTarget == True:
                count += 1
                Random_x = random.randrange(0, display_width)
                Random_y = random.randrange(0, display_height)
                GameTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                Get_Event_Time(GameTime)

    if count == NoOfTargets:
        GameEnded = True

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    Target(Random_x, Random_y, Target_radius, red)
    pygame.display.update()
```